# Remove x tips outside Line Chart on crossing of X,Y axes at the beginning Chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js, linechart, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

The question is, if it's possible to remove this extra ticks

[image: extra ticks]

from the chart, to let the graph start exactly from the beginning, without those extra ticks. It's very important for me, because originally I need to hide X axes, and it looks a bit weird, when the chart starts not from the beginning

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `tickLength` to `0` in the `grid` config:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          tickLength: 0,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the best way to do that

```
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
      drawTicks: false,
    },
  },
```

Just add  `drawTicks: false` and it will solve the problem.